# Data parallelism in Tensorflow. Which one is better?

Tags: python, tensorflow, parallel-processing

I came across 2 examples of data parallelism in Tensorflow.

1) The CIFAR-10 example: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/image/cifar10/cifar10_multi_gpu_train.py#L65

2) Effective Tensorflow https://github.com/vahidk/EffectiveTensorflow

As I understand in [1] We create a new copy of the model per GPU and collect and minimize loss later
while in [2] We break down one minibatch into chunks for different GPUs.

[2] Seems much more simpler to implement to me.

Are there any advantages of one approach over the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both implementations use the same kind of parallelization over the minibatch. In both, each gpu gets its own graph of the model but all gpus with id >= 1 get a variable scope with `reuse=True`, therefore all will work on the same variables.

The loop in [1] at line 170 is nearly identical to the loop `for i in range(num_gpus):` inside of the `make_parallel` function in [2]. The only difference is that [1] splits the `tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.1).minimize(tf.reduce_mean(loss))` into getting the gradients first (`opt.compute_gradients` at line 187) and applying them later, after the parallel loop (`opt.apply_gradients` at line 205). They do this to average all the gradients of one minibatch before applying them.

Comment: Would there be a reason for one approach to be faster?

Comment: @Rahul not really, it is basically both the same approach.